# SQL Server 2005 Express Edition - Replication Support

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

We move from sql 2008 standard to express. I know publication/subscription is not allowed in sql 2008 express. I would like to know if is any other option for replication in express version?

Regards

Comment: What was your reason for moving to a lower grade version of the product? Were you aware that you were going to lose the ability to have a replication publisher?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL Server 2008 Express may participate as a subscriber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686.aspx), it just cannot be a publisher.  However, [two-way merge replication is supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151819.aspx).

Comment: I already know what you said. So i need any new solution if exist?

Comment: Your post says that subscription is not allowed, which is not true. I was clarifying that subscription **is** allowed, in case you just need to subscribe and not publish.

Comment: +1 for what I would consider a valid and valuable answer. @senzacionale: Hopefully it wasn't you that downvoted this answer. Your question leaves a lot open to assumption and interpretation (of what you know or don't know about SQL Express) and Stephen's answer offered you information you may or may not have known. Downvoting on good answers to your questions is not likely to get you many answers here.

Comment: no i didn't vote anything. I never downgrade voting...